# IpyLeaflet not displaying on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gis, google-earth-engine, ipyleaflet

I am using some documentation code from [Ipyleaflet](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles

m = Map(
    basemap=basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.NASAGIBS.ModisTerraTrueColorCR, "2017-04-08"),
    center=(52.204793, 360.121558),
    zoom=4
)

m
```

[image: Jupyter notebook example]

And still it does not show.
I have tried both [https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html](http://pip%20install%20ipyleaflet%20jupyter%20nbextension%20enable%20--py%20--sys-prefix%20ipyleaflet)

Some settings of my machine:
Python 3.8.5
pip 21.3 from /Users/cmougan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

```
(base) Carloss-MacBook-Pro:~ cmougan$ jupyter nbextension list
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /Users/cmougan/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      spellchecker/main  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      nbresuse/main  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbresuse/main
      plotlywidget/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-black-master/jupyter-black  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      fairlearn-widget/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X fairlearn-widget/extension
      fairlearn-widget/index  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X fairlearn-widget/index
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
  config dir: /Users/cmougan/opt/anaconda3/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
  config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      plotlywidget/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

Comment: Somehow it works in JupyterLab....